# Limit fgets input to up to a certain number of characters

Tags: c, strings, io

This question is an extension of [this other question from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66249671/how-can-i-limit-stop-the-number-of-characters-fgets-reads).

The objective is to limit the input of characters read by fgets to up to a certain number of characters. And in the following code, that I've come up with as a solution, we are working with a limit of 10 characters as an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char v[12];
    
    printf("Type a word with up to 10 chracters:\n");
    //Loop checks if fgets succeeded and if there is '\n' in the string:
    while (!fgets(v, 12, stdin) || strcspn(v, "\n") == 11){
        if(feof(stdin)) {
             printf("Error: End of file reached.\n");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Error: The word is longer than 10 characters, try again.\n");
        for(int ch=getchar(); ch != '\n' && ch != EOF; ch=getchar());
        printf("Type a word with up to 10 chracters:\n");
    }
    v[strcspn(v, "\n")] = '\0';
    
    printf("%s\n", v);

    return 0;
}
```

It works as intended. However [@chux-ReinstateMonica has pointed out that there may still be corner weaknesses and possible improvements to be made to this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66249671/how-can-i-limit-stop-the-number-of-characters-fgets-reads#comment117130088_66250051).

So, how can this code/solution be improved?

Answer (score 4):

This would obviously be better as a function, so we can call with different parameters.

Instead of repeating the constant `12` in the `fgets()` call, we could simply use `sizeof v`.  Then it remains consistent if we change `v`.

Instead of `strcspn()` with only one character, I'd prefer `strchr()`.  Conveniently, that returns a null pointer if not found, so we don't need to calculate the length to search.  And we shouldn't repeat the search to replace the newline with null character.

Error messages should go to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

We can skip the rest of line with a simple `scanf("%*[^\n]")` (note the `*` to suppress assignment).  That would replace the `ch` loop.

Comment: Make a function: Yes. -- Use `sizeof v` instead of `12`: In a function I think the maximum number of characters (10 in the example) would be more important, and it would better to simply assume that the char array is large enough (length of at least the maximum number of character + 2).

Comment: Use `strchr()` instead of `strcspn()`: Good idea. -- Send error messages to `stderr`: Yes. -- Use `scanf("%*[^\n]")` to clear excess characters: That would leave a `'\n'` in `stdin` that would be read by `fgets()`.

Comment: `sizeof v` wouldn't be necessary in a function, as caller should pass buffer and capacity.  Yes, we'd need a `getchar()` after that `scanf()` (which we could use to check for `EOF`) - sorry for not being explicit about that.

Comment: Is there a performance advantage to using `scanf("%*[^\n]")` instead of the `getchar()` loop?

Comment: Unlikely - just readability.  BTW, it occurs to me that we could simply add `%*c` to the format string to consume the newline - no need to check the return value here, as the subsequent `fgets()` provides all the check we need (but I'd comment why we're ignoring it).

Comment: No, for some reason I've never understood adding `%*c` to make `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c")` doesn't work, the `\n` still remains in `stdin` as if there wasn't the `%*c` specifier. And it is necessary to use 2 consecutive scanfs like this `scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");` to clean everything (so it would be better to use `getchar()` instead of the second scanf).

Comment: "add `%*c` to the format string to consume the newline" as with `%*[^\n]%*c`  fails to read a trailing newline if it is the first character.

Comment: @isrnick: To properly detect rare input errors, 2 consecutive `scanf`s and/or `getchar()` should check the result before proceeding to the next.

Comment: `scanf("%*[^\n]")` does not quite "skip the rest of line". It fails to read the `'\n'` at the end of the line. Also, its return value is important to detect input errors.

Comment: A nice attribute about `strcspn()` is `v[strcspn(v, "\n\r")] = '\0';` to handle text files from foreign systems.

Comment: @chux: (1) yes, we need to read the newline as well as the rest of the non-newline characters.  I didn't think that needed saying (but earlier comments proved otherwise!).  (2) Can you give an example of where a `scanf()`/`getchar()` could fail but not be detected on the next stream operation?  (3) I like that `strcspn()` use to handle CRLF so simply.

Comment: TobySpeight Pedantic concern: The rare input error causes `scanf(), getchar()` to return `EOF`. The next input function may/may not return `EOF` - it depends on the nature of the input error.  So without checking the first, an input error may lack detection.  This is unlike "end-of-file", where "If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, **or** if the stream is at end-of-file".  Some [additional thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32654299/2410359).

Answer (score 3):

**Does not detect input errors on `stdin`**

When `fgets()` returns `NULL` due to an *input error*, code simply loops when a loop exit is more common.  If the input error is permanent, code is stuck in a infinite loop.

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

Rather than 12, 11, etc, use a `#define BUF_N 12` and code accordingly.

```
// while (!fgets(v, 12, stdin) || strcspn(v, "\n") == 11){
while (!fgets(v, BUF_N, stdin) || strcspn(v, "\n") == BUF_N - 1){
```

**Good use of `int`**

```
//  vvv --- proper type to save the typical 257 different responses from `fgetc()`
for(int ch=getchar(); ch != '\n' && ch != EOF; ch=getchar());
```

**Spell check**

chracters --> characters

---

**Sample code**

Following OP's style, as a *function* returning a flag rather than printing errors:

```
// Look for an input <= N-2 non-\n characters.
// Return error/EOF flag
bool OP_readline(char *v, size_t n, const char *re_prompt) {
  char *fgets_retval;
  size_t len = 0;
  while ((fgets_retval = fgets(v, n, stdin)) != NULL && (len = strcspn(v, "\n")) + 1 == n) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
      ;
    }
    if (ch == EOF) {
      return true; // Error or EOF;
    }
    if (re_prompt) {
      fputs(re_prompt, stdout);
      fflush(stdout):
    }
    len = 0;
  }
  v[len] = 0;
  return fgets_retval == NULL;
}
```

**Other improvements**

1. Better code would not need a buffer of +1 size.  This allows one to read directly into an array of size `N` without providing a `N+1` size array just for the benefit the read function.  Detecting long lines is the read function's problem and should not oblige the caller to provide a +1 buffer to solve it.
2. *Null character* input can fool above code a bit, but leave that for another day.
3. Detection/Handling of extreme `n`.  Should be in the range `2 <= n <= INT_MAX`, or some other well thought out limits.
4. Consider a `prompt` parameter too.

Comment: Very important about input errors; should also detect input errors from `getchar`.

Comment: @Neil Agreed.  Good to test `ch`.

Comment: returning `true` for errors is confusing. Most other functions return `true` on success. `ferror` is a notable exception, of course.

Comment: @RolandIllig Yes, `stream` was a poor choice.  Code amended.

Answer (score 2):

Really nice style; super clear. I'll try not to duplicate existing and really good answers. What I think you intend to do is a kind of state machine looking something like this:

[image: The state machine with fgets and getchar.]

The error, in this case, includes `stdin` EOF before return was pressed. However, you are only checking for EOF and ignoring other errors, as pointed out. I believe that the `fgets`, `getchar`, and `error` states will probably make your code clearer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

// user-defined errno values; should all be negative to avoid conflicts
enum { NOT_POSIX_COMPLIANT = -2, EOF_ERROR };

/** Blocks, prompting the user again and again. If true, `v` is full up to
 `v_size`, including "". If false, `errno` is set to and expanded range. `v`
 must be capable of holding `v_size` bytes. */
static int prompt(char *const v, const size_t v_size) {
    size_t len;
    int ch;
    assert(v && v_size > 2 && v_size <= INT_MAX);
    //Loop checks if `fgets` succeeded and if there is '\n' in the string:
    for( ; ; ) {
        printf("Type a word with up to %zu chracters:\n", v_size - 2);
        if(!fgets(v, (int)v_size, stdin)) goto eof;
        if(v[len = strcspn(v, "\n")] == '\n') return v[len] = '\0', 1;
        //fprintf(stderr, "Error: input line too long.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Discarding malformed line.\n");
        while(ch = getchar(), ch != '\n') if(ch == EOF) goto eof;
    }
eof:
    if(feof(stdin)) errno = EOF_ERROR; // in this use-case, it is an error
    else if(!errno) errno = NOT_POSIX_COMPLIANT; // "Extension to the ISO"
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char v[12];

    if(!prompt(v, sizeof v)) goto error;
    printf("%s\n", v);

    return 0;

error:
    switch(errno) {
    case NOT_POSIX_COMPLIANT:
        fprintf(stderr, "An unknown read error occurred.\n"); break;
    case EOF_ERROR:
        fprintf(stderr, "Premature EOF.\n"); break;
    default:
        perror("input");
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

I've re-arraged some stuff using what it says in the man pages about errors to match the diagram. It's hard to do interactive programmes in purely `ISO C`. I would consider, depending on your application, returning failure immediately upon mis-formed input. Especially if you think there is a good reason to pipe data to `stdin`.

Comment: Consider a redirected `stdin` where the last line of input is `"abc"` with no `'\n'`.  `prompt(v, 12)` here rejects that short line with `"Error: input line too long.\n"` instead of accepting it. IMO, better to accept such lines.  Lines that end with an end-of-file rather than a `'\n'` are often a corner case to deliberate.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica good catch; there are definitely even more edge cases that I didn't think of. On my computer, an EOF in state `getchar` causes the message `too long` and then it keeps reading. I think this is probably undesirable, too. I think a terminal control library is really what is needed, but probably overkill for most applications.

Comment: Neil, Good catch on the "keeps reading".  IMO, the standard C library simple lacks a nice "read a line into a buffer" function.  `fgets()` is OK, but has weaknesses.

Answer (score 1):

IMO a much simpler solution is to use [POSIX `getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html).  And if your platform doesn't provide `getline()`, there are more than a few open-source implementations available.

Bare code to illustrate the processing in a smaller number of lines (as in without scroll bars...):

```
int main()
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    for ( ;; )
    {
        printf( "Type a word with up to 10 characters:\n" );
        ssize_t result = getline( &line, &len, stdin );
        if ( result < 0 )
        {
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
        if ( strlen( line ) <= 10 )
        {
            break;
        }

        printf( "Error: The word is longer than 10 characters, try again.\n" );
    }

    printf( "Your input: %s\n",  line );    
    return 0;
}
```

The use of `strcspn()` and `strlen()` could be made more efficient so the line only gets traversed once, but we're dealing with user input here so code clarity overrides almost every performance consideration.

With full error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    for ( ;; )
    {
        printf( "Type a word with up to 10 characters:\n" );

        ssize_t result = getline( &line, &len, stdin );
        if ( result < 0 )
        {
            if ( feof( stdin ) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "EOF reached\n" );
            }
            else
            {
                perror( "getline(..., stdin)" );
            }

            free( line );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

        if ( strlen( line ) <= 10 )
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("Error: The word is longer than 10 characters, try again.\n");
    }

    printf( "Your input: %s\n",  line );

    free( line );

    return 0;
}
```

As a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getLine( unsigned int maxLen )
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    // sanity check passed variable
    if ( 0 == maxLen )
    {
        return( NULL );
    }

    for ( ;; )
    {
        printf( "Type a word with up to %u characters:\n", maxLen );

        ssize_t result = getline( &line, &len, stdin );
        if ( result < 0 )
        {
            if ( feof( stdin ) )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "EOF reached\n" );
            }
            else
            {
                perror( "getline(..., stdin)" );
            }

            free( line );
            return( NULL );
        }

        line[ strcspn( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

        if ( strlen( line ) <= maxLen )
        {
            break;
        }

        printf( "Error: The word is longer than %u characters, try again.\n",
            maxLen );
    }

    printf( "Your input: %s\n",  line );

    return( line );
}
```

Comment: I was assuming that the code was posted as an attempt to reimplement `getline()`, but you're right that's not stated, so good answer!

Comment: What is the `size` used as an argument in the `getline()` function? Please elaborate on why a solution using `getline()` is better in your opinion. And if possible tell me where I can find a reliable open-source implementation of `getline()` that I can use with MinGW and other Windows compilers.

Comment: @isrnick *Please elaborate on why a solution using `getline()` is better in your opinion.*  Because "Get complete line, check length" is a lot simpler and less bug-prone than "read string, check length, see if it ends with a newline, if it doesn't clear input buffer"?  Count the lines of code - and remember to count `while (!fgets(v, 12, stdin) || strcspn(v, "\n") == 11)` as five or six lines because you've put that many operations there, and `for(int ch=getchar(); ch != '\n' && ch != EOF; ch=getchar());` counts as five to seven also. Every line of code you write is a chance to create bugs.

Comment: (cont)  Your code will have been tested a handful of times against a smattering of different input - if you tested it at all...  Your system's `getline()` implementation has been tested probably **trillions** of times - if not more - against all kinds of input.  Take glibc's implementation, for example.  It was developed by an experienced team, formally reviewed by multiple experienced developers, passed through rigorous formal testing, and been open for comment for probably several decades now.

Comment: A weakness to `getline( &line, &len, stdin );` is that it allows a nefarious user to overwhelm memory resources with an excessive long line.  Defensive programming prevents that.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If that's something you need to protect against, that's what limits are for.  Because if overwhelming memory resources is a threat, there are much simpler ways to do that.  `tail -f /dev/zero` or `dd bs=1024k if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/asdf` come to mind immediately.  Nevermind anyone with access to a compiler...